# Altium Redundant ECO

Tags: altium

Hello I am doing board layout in Altium but whenever I import changes from schematics Altium performs a redundant ECO where it just adds and deletes the same 39 components. For example:

1) I import changes from my schematic file and get an error that 39 components can't match: 
[image]

2) For some reason it can't match component classes even tho the class names are the same...
[image]

3) So I match Components from sheet 7 with components from sheet 7 and components from sheet 8 with components from sheet 8:
[image]

4) Click continue to issue an ECO but all Altium does is remove those 39 components (and all their respective nets and footprints) and then just re-adds them without making any actual change to the board:

[image]
[image]

No changes on the board happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Go to the PCB.
Click Project --> Component Links.
Make sure all the parts are linked.
Click OK.

Go to the SCH.
Design --> Update PCB.
There should be nothing to update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a board. It only worked if I did Design->Update PCB twice. I think my problem was due to a design with "Channels".